# Replacement for ternary operator

Tags: c

Let **params** be a pointer to a structure which contains a member **valueInt**. I want to check the value of **valueInt** in the pointed structure but only after checking if the pointer is not a NULL. So I tried conditional operator like:

```
if ((NULL == params) ? 1: (cJSON_Int != params->valueInt)) 
{
 // Do Something
}
```

My requirement is to check the pointer NULL equivalency first and then dereference it. But I am not supposed to use ternary operator according to our company guidelines. What are other ways in place of the conditional statement that I can use here (something like short-circuit statements)?

Comment: Those are some pretty poor guidelines. Anyway, does the code you showed capture the desired logic?

Comment: Why not use a regular &&? It is short-circuited, so it will immediately exit if the pointer is NULL.

Comment: I just gave some example code!
I wanted some functionality like in ADA we have short circuits:
AND THEN / OR THEN

Comment: `if ( NULL == params || cJSON_Int != params->valueInt)` will shortcut. `&&` and `||` will have the right side evaluated only if strictly necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the criticism!

Comment: This isn't surprising. I've found that organizations that ban `if (params == NULL)` in favor of yoda conditions such as `if (NULL == params)` also tend to ban the ternary operator. And vice versa. That said, there's no need for a ternary here. Use the fact that `&&` and `||` shortcut. The code is cleaner, shorter, and more obvious than the equivalent ternary.

Answer (score 2):

The logical OR operator is a short-circuit operator, meaning it won't evaluate the right operand if it can determine the final result of the expression from the left operand.

So you can do this:

```
if ((NULL == params) || (cJSON_Int != params->valueInt))
{
    ...
}
```

This will enter the `if` block if `params` is NULL OR the second condition is true.  The second part won't be evaluated if `NULL == params` evaluates to true.

Comment: His original code will enter "Do something" in case NULL == params.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted!

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: "*To better reflect the logic you have*" :-)

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier (and more readable) to use the explicit cases in a branch:

```
if (params == NULL) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // It is not NULL, check value
    if (cJSON_Int != params->valueInt) {
        // value is not cJSON_Int
    } else {
        // optional else
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought of using but I didn't want my code to look this big. I wanted one line logic. Anyway Thanks